# How to convert markdown to inline HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, markdown

With [Markdown library](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) I can do the following:

```
>  markdown.toHTML ("test `some code`")
<- "<p>test <code>some code</code></p>"
```

so it is easy to convert simple wiki text to HTML. However, resulting HTML is a *block*, where I'd (also) need inline HTML, for example to use as `<input>` label. So, I'd need some function or a simple enough piece of code to do this:

```
>  ... ("test `some code`")
<- "test <code>some code</code>"
```

Of course I can easily strip leading/trailing `p` tags from the string, but that feels like a hack. Is there a better way (or maybe a better library) for this?

Comment: you want to trim out the root element but keeping the inner html as-is?

Comment: Don't complicate your life. Just get the content from the <p> tag with JS or jQuery.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I don't need lists or paragraphs in certain cases, but I want to be able to use bold text etc.

Comment: Is this in the browser of in NodeJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In The Browser

you can assist `jquery` to do that by calling `.html()`

### http://plnkr.co/edit/Bkzp3het37F3S1E1VVIt?p=preview

```
var html = markdown.toHTML('test `some code`');
var innerHtml = $(html).html();
alert(innerHtml);
```

## In NodeJS

You can achieve this by using 3rd party library to parse html named [`cheerio`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)

**js:**

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var markdown = require("markdown").markdown;

var html = markdown.toHTML("test `some code`");

var $ = cheerio.load(html);
var innerHtml = $.root().contents().html();

console.log(innerHtml);
```

**output:**

```
test <code>some code</code>
```

---

in addition you can wrap things up in a single function like this:

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

function getRidOfRootElement(html){
    return cheerio.load(html).root().contents().html();
}
```

Comment: Isn't an HTML parsing lib a little heavy handed? Why not use a DocumentFragment instead which is already in the DOM Spec.

Comment: yeah but isn't this hosted on nodejs?

Comment: Oh! this is NodeJS?! I thought it was in the browser. Nevermind.

Comment: Still feels somewhat hacky, but at least better than just removing `<p>` tag.